# Why Occur ActivityManager ANR on android?

Tags: android

my app often occur logcat ActivityManager `ANR` message and app died.

my logcat

```
03-23 09:14:42.039 1439-1465/system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid (kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid/.BlackEyeActivity)
       PID: 4340
       Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send key event because the focused window has not finished processing all of the input events that were previously delivered to it.  Outbound queue length: 0.  Wait queue length: 1.)
       Load: 2.46 / 0.85 / 0.42
       CPU usage from 31258ms to 0ms ago:
     9.4% 1142/mediaserver: 8.9% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 1777 minor
     5.3% 3871/kworker/1:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel + 5.1% iowait
     5.2% 1439/system_server: 3.3% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 6114 minor
     4.4% 1135/surfaceflinger: 2.8% user + 1.5% kernel + 0% iowait / faults: 1451 minor
     3.1% 1551/com.android.systemui: 2.8% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 3042 minor
     2.1% 4004/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel + 2% iowait
     1.8% 1057/jbd2/sda1-8: 0% user + 0% kernel + 1.7% iowait
     1% 1968/android.process.media: 0.7% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 2441 minor
     0.9% 1154/adbd: 0.1% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 6067 minor
     0.4% 1139/debuggerd: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 2986 minor
     0.3% 3766/kworker/u4:1: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
     0.2% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
     0.2% 1090/logd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 22 minor
     0.2% 2271/com.android.settings: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 367 minor 1 major
     0.2% 6/kworker/u4:0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
     0.1% 1572/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
     0.1% 1793/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 330 minor
     0.1% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
     0.1% 1750/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1716 minor
     0% 1783/org.android_x86.analytics: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 114 minor
     0% 1048/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1168/mysqld: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
     0% 14/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1149/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2472 minor
     0% 1532/sdcard: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1738/com.google.android.inputmethod.korean: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
     0% 2085/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 281 minor
    +0% 4340/kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 4352/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 4983/app_process: 0% user + 0% kernel
       64% TOTAL: 31% user + 30% kernel + 1.4% iowait + 0.9% softirq
       CPU usage from 1588ms to 2097ms later:
     138% 4340/kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid: 51% user + 87% kernel / faults: 544 minor
       99% 4656/ackeyeonandroid: 23% user + 75% kernel
       13% 4984/MediaCodec_loop: 7.9% user + 5.9% kernel
       11% 4987/le.h264.encoder: 9.9% user + 1.9% kernel
       11% 4989/pool-6-thread-1: 7.9% user + 3.9% kernel
       1.9% 4519/GLThread 248: 1.9% user + 0% kernel
     13% 1142/mediaserver: 13% user + 0% kernel
       7.8% 4540/CameraPreviewTh: 7.8% user + 0% kernel
       7.8% 4851/CameraPreviewTh: 7.8% user + 0% kernel
     1.9% 1439/system_server: 1.9% user + 0% kernel
       81% TOTAL: 34% user + 45% kernel + 1% iowait
```

I searched android developer site.

when occur ANR ?
- User input via touchscreen has not been processed within 5 seconds
- When the broadcast was not processed within 10 seconds
- When the service is not processed within 20 seconds

but It does not belong to them.

why occur ANR my app?